# Java fails with insufficient memory... but only for one user

Tags: java, memory, jvm, redhat

We're running RHEL 6.1 with Java 1.6.0_29. Running java -version (or any other invocation of Java) yields:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
```

However... this only happens for one user. Other users can start the JVM successfully. All users point to the same Java installation. Shot in the dark, but has anyone encountered something like this?

**UPDATE:**

It turned out the issue was the limit on the number of processes for the user. We recently upgraded our box and added a ton of cores, so the JVM was allocating more threads for parallel GC based on the number of cores. We increased the process limit for the user and Java is running happily for the moment. Long-term solution will probably be to tweak the Java GC settings.

Comment: Do you use cgroups to limit the resources?

Comment: Sounds like there's something else running that's already taking up all of the resources.  Can't really tell based on this much data.

Comment: I've seen the same issue show up in RHEL 6 because of in-memory file-caching.  It's been a number of years since we fixed it, so I can't remember exactly what the culprit was, but do remember that clearing the memory-resident file cache did the trick.

Comment: Also, check user limits for this particular users shell  ("ulimit -a" in bash) and see if there are low limits on anything

Comment: @lreeder - yep, the issue was limits on number of processes for the user. We updated our box recently and added a lot of cores, so the JVM was allocating more threads for GC based on the # of cores. Thanks!